# How to Access an NSMutableArray from a Different Class

Tags: arrays, xcode, class, variables, nsmutablearray

I have been researching for 2 days now and cannot seem to teach myself how to access my NSMutableArray from a different class. I want to fill my new "buildButtonText" array with info from my old "selectedArray" array.
I will post all related code and I would appreciate anybody taking the time to help me find what is hanging me up. Thanks in advance for your time.

In ViewController.h:

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableArray *selectedArray;
    }
    @property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedArray;
    @end
```

In ViewController.m:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "ViewController2.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
     selectedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    //....Other methods which dictate the objects in the final "selectedArray"....

    -(IBAction)Next:(id)sender{
    ViewController2 *nextViewController = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    nextViewController.buildButtonText = selectedArray;
    }
    //.....Or perhaps here I should use "prepareForSegue" to pass objects...?
```

In ViewController2.h:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{
    NSMutableArray *buildButtonText;
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buildButtonText;
    @end
```

In ViewController2.m:

```
    #import "ViewController2.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController2 ()
    @end

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
    buildButtonText=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Count of array: %d", [buildButtonText count]);
    }
```

And the Log returns "0" items in the array. I have also tried to ask the variable from the 2nd view controller and if this is in fact the proper protocol I would appreciate a brief demonstration. In case you could not tell from my code I am fairly new.

Comment: I assume at this line: nextViewController.buildButtonText = selectedArray; that selectedArray has objects in it ? Also how are you presenting ViewController2 ? I'd be tempted to create a custom init method for ViewController 2 and then just pass the selectedArray into that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Yes there are objects in the array. They are added and used in the first view controller. I made ViewController 2 through storyboard and connected the transition via a "next" button. Are you saying I should try to call the variable from ViewController2.m? Would I do this in the viewDidload? Thank you for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use prepareForSegue?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"])
    {
        SECOND_VIEW_CONTROLLER *svc=[segue destinationViewController];
        svc.NSMUTABLEARRAY_TO_RECEIVE=NSMUTABLEARRAY_TO_SEND;
    }
}
```

Maybe this helps? Just replace the caps words.

I just started iOS app dev recently and I used something similar in the same situation, works perfectly! Make sure you import the `.h` file of your second `ViewController` into the first one.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response. This seems like it should work but I am receiving a "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. The segue identifier, header files, and all variables seem in order but I will play with this for the next day and hopefully be able to 'accept' this answer.

Comment: @Wisam22 hmmm, which selector is supposedly unrecognized?

Comment: Actually the 'unrecognized selector' was just a product of me removing a method and forgetting to remove the connection in the storyboard. However, the 2nd array still is returning 0 items in my second view controller.

Comment: Is there any other allocation/initialization required to allow the controllers to see each other?

Comment: @Wisam22 the destinationViewController selector of segue returns the instance of the ViewController which will be instantiated by the segue. Also keep in mind that prepareForSegue happens before the second ViewController's viewDidLoad smethod.

Comment: YES! Thank you. After much grief I finally realized I was calling "selectedArray" instead of "_selectedArray." I am learning this language the hard way haha.